# Spring Boot Admin - Persist applications and events

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-admin

I have a problem with Spring Boot Admin: after restarting the server instance, it loses all applications and events.

This is the schema and steps: server instance that monitor application A, B and C.

1. Start server instance
2. Start app A, B and C
3. Stop app C and server instance
4. Restart server instance
5. At this point the event journal is cleared and the application C in not in the application list

How can I manage this situation? Maybe, I have to persist these information on db. But, I can't find anything useful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Hazelcast** for make apps and events persistent. Take a look at SBA documentation (clustering paragraph).

Add Hazelcast dependency in *pom.xml*:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
    <artifactId>hazelcast</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Then, in *application.properties*:

```
spring.boot.admin.hazelcast.enabled=true
spring.boot.admin.hazelcast.event-store=spring-boot-admin-event-store
```

Instantiate a *HazelcastConfig*

```
    @Bean
public Config config() {
    MapConfig eventStoreMap = new MapConfig("spring-boot-admin-event-store")
            .setInMemoryFormat(InMemoryFormat.OBJECT)
            .setBackupCount(1)
            .setEvictionPolicy(EvictionPolicy.NONE)
            .setMergePolicyConfig(new MergePolicyConfig(PutIfAbsentMapMergePolicy.class.getName(), 100))
            .setMapStoreConfig(new MapStoreConfig().setImplementation(new HazelcastEventImplementation()));

    Config config = new Config();
    config.addMapConfig(eventStoreMap);
    config.setProperty("hazelcast.jmx", "true");

    return config;
}
```

Finally, implement a *MapStore< InstanceId, ArrayList >* class with your preferred persistence method (in my example configuration *HazelcastEventImplementation.java*).

Comment: What should be the content of HazelcastEventImplementation.java Can you please provide that please.

Answer (score 0):

As far I understood, you have already stopped application C and on re-starting server instance (Spring boot admin- SBA), you cannot see the application C.

But I guess this is the intended behavior, SBA doesn't register offline applications. This is because applications first register to SBA and not the other way round. In this case application, C is offline.

However, once an application has registered to SBA and it went offline, you can still see it in the list with status as offline. But the SBA server restart will create new server instance with no knowledge of previously registered applications.

If I haven't clearly understood, can you please provide more information.

Comment: Hi Mohit, first of all thanks for your answare. You understood the situation, but what happen if all my applications goes down (included the SBA server)? How can I retrieve all application and all events? I can't know what happen (event journey) and which application is under monitoring.