# Spring event lifecycle

Tags: java, spring, events, event-handling

To understand if the spring events fits the task im working on I need to understand how they work, where are they stored?
as I can guess they are stored in a spring application context and disappears if the application crashes, is my guess correct?

Comment: Are you talking about Spring events such as the ones discussed on https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/event.html or https://www.baeldung.com/spring-events?
Unless you work with a persistent queue such as Kafka events are in-memory only so not available after a restart. (or Hazelcast, see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59067599/1297789)

Comment: @Omnibyte I used Baeldung guide while testing them

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/15228464/mmmetafool can you elaborate on what the requirements are for your task? That way it may be possible to determine if Spring events match your use case.

Comment: @Omnibyte yes, I need to get events-like info when an object changes its state, choosing between spring event and Kafka messages, 
if spring events would be lost when the app crashes don't think they would fit the task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring events are intended to use when calling methods directly would create too much coupling. If you need to track events for auditing or replay purposes you have to save the events yourself. Based on your comments, there are many ways to achieve this, based on the topology and purpose of the application (list not complete):

1. Model entities that represent the events and store them in a [repository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html)
2. Incorporate a message broker such as [Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/) that support message persistence
3. Install an in-memory cache such as [Hazelcast](https://hazelcast.com/clients/java/)
4. Use a cloud message service such as [AWS SQS](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/)

Lastly, please make sure that you carefully evaluate which options suits your needs best. Options 2 to 4 all introduce heavy complexity and distributed applications can bring sorrow and misery to your life. Go for the simplest option if you can and only resort the other options if absolutely necessary.